# Cannot find expression blend in menu after installing windows phone sdk 7.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I typed expression in windows menu, I have nothing.

I have visual studio 2010 but not express edition, does it requires expression edition ?

Update: seems some people don't know expression blend is free with windows phone sdk 7.1:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27570

> The Windows Phone SDK includes the following Microsoft Expression
>
> Blend SDK for Windows Phone 7 Microsoft Expression Blend SDK for
> Windows Phone OS 7.1

Happy gift :)

Except I can't find it yet :(

Comment: Expression Blend is a designer-centric IDE for WPF, Silverlight and WP7.  You don't need it to create WP7 apps, and I don't think it comes as part of the SDK.  I'm not even sure if there is a "free" version of it.

Comment: yes there is a free version precisely with the sdk that's why I'm asking see my update :)

Comment: Interesting.  Reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you download correct setup of [Windows Phone SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570). `Visual Studio Express` is not needed when you have another version of `Visual Studio 2010` (and it don't installed automatically in that situation)

You can try to `Repair` installed SDK with the same setup file (just select Repair/Reinstall option)

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project in Visual Studio and see if you have "Open in Expression Blend". If you do go ahead and click it. IF not, uninstall your SDK and install it again using express settings.

If it gives you an error when launching and you have installed Visual Studio 11 Dev Preview follow this link for a fix: [Known Issues with Dev Preview](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/38847ac8-e387-4af6-8411-c9c95c27e67f)

Comment: I have only open marketplace toolkit. I'm not using vs2011 only vs2010.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the SDK?

Comment: Strange. In that case I'm out of ideas. If I come across something that might help you I'll get back and let you know. One more thing you can try is to uninstall everything that had the word "Expression" in it from your control panel, stuff like Expression Blend, Expression Web, Expression Studio, etc. and then do a clean re-install.